# Selecting quite a lot of Size and Quantity

Tags: forms, mobile, gestures

This UI is for a B2B web ecommerce page, where a buyer can enter quantities for multiple sizes of a product. They first click a size in the top row which reveals up/down arrows on the qty, which the user than taps to increase or decrease qty as needed.

[image: tab Size Quantity]

[image: on the click: up and down arrows to change the quantity of the Size 6]

[image]

Can you suggest any alternative or new UI that save space but is scalable and is suitable for mobile gestures?

Comment: What is the use case for this interface?

Comment: To be placed in a Product Page in a B2B Ecommerce website.
1 Buyer "Searches for products"
2 Selects "Quantity" for each "Size" 
3 Click "Add to order" to Add the selection to the current order

Answer (score 5):

Current design has some bad features:

- Per-column layout isn't scalable, as the screen width is limited. And horisontal swipe for scrolling could conflict with screen changing gesture interaction.
- Per-column interaction isn't convenient, as the data is best readed row by row.
- Increase and decrease buttons rather small for touch interaction.
  [image]

You could use more convenient layout, which has no mentioned issues:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I totally agree with both your point, the only thing is that I am trying to stay as short as possible in terms of verticality and 4/5 might be the average number of rows in this feature.

Comment: @fdonelli Ignoring usability saves the screen space but cuts the money. That's why usability is important.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for your suggestion anyway, I am reworking on that anyhow.

Comment: The version of @Alexy supports the mental model of users better.